# A question about circular shift group action.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-actions, cyclic-groups

I'm reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.08389.pdf) and I'm stuck at example 1.2.

We have the cyclic group $G = \mathbb{Z}_6$ and for $g \in G$ we define the action on the set $N = \{1,2,3\}$ as $g \cdot n := g+n \, \mod 3$. It is stated as circular shift to the *right*. Now, if we take $g=\bar{2}$ and we sum it to all the elements of $N$, we obtain

\begin{align}
& \bar{2} + 1 \, \mod \,3 = 3 \mod \,3 = 0 \\
& \bar{2} + 2 \, \mod \,3 = 4 \mod \,3 = 1 \\
& \bar{2} + 3 \, \mod \,3 = 5 \mod \,3 = 2 \\
\end{align}

This doesn't actually look like a circular shift as I end up in an element which is not in the set $N$..

Also, reading the paper, it states that this circular shift to the right should be equivalent to the permutation matrix

$$2_N = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

but to be honest I cannot see this. In fact, taken a vector $\textbf{x} = [x_1,x_2,x_3]^T$ and considering the matrix vector product $2_N\textbf{x} = [x_2, x_3,x_1]$ which looks like a circular shift to the **left**.

Comment: You add a class $\overline{2}$ to a number $1$, and then say you got $0$, which is not in $N$. But you cannot add classes and numbers. You have $\overline{2}+\overline{1}=\overline{3}=\overline{0}$.

Comment: but $1$ is not a class, it's an element on the set $N$ on which the group is acting, so I don't understand your comment.

Comment: You need to say how the action is well-defined. What exactly is $\overline{2}+1$ then? Indeed, it is not an action, if the result is not in $N$. Can you fix this?

Comment: I would say $\bar{2} + \bar{1}$ mod 3 but that would be $\bar{0}$ which again is not in N.. mmh

Comment: No idea, but in any case the "$\text{mod } 3$" in the LHS is an undue forcing, not entailed by action(?)'s definition.